# Why is returning NextResponse.next() throwing a TypeError in Next.js middleware?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to implement simple middleware for auth routes in Next.js 12.1.6. It's supposed to check for authentication headers, validate tokens and proceed accordingly.

Looking at some examples online, seems like it should return `NextResponse.next()` to proceed (like calling `next()` in Express) and `new Response()` if we don't want the request to complete. Returning `new Response()` is working fine but `NextResponse.next()` throws `TypeError: resolver is not a function`

```
// _middleware.ts
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"

const authMiddleware = async (req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) => {
    if (validated) {
       return NextResponse.next()
     } else {
       return new Response("Unauthorized")
     } 
    }

export default authMiddleware
```

I have tried `NextResponse.rewrite()` using `req.page.name` but using a dynamic url doesn't work. `NextResponse.redirect()` creates an infinite loop.

Seems like the problem is in my local setup, thanks to Mark for figuring that out.

Here's some more details:

Call Stack

```
Call Stack
Object.apiResolver
file:/Users/adk/Projects/myproject/nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js (185:15)
runMicrotasks
<anonymous>
processTicksAndRejections
node:internal/process/task_queues (96:5)
async DevServer.runApi
file:/Users/adk/Projects/myproject/nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js (395:9)
async Object.fn
file:/Users/adk/Projects/myproject/nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js (496:37)
async Router.execute
file:/Users/adk/Projects/myproject/nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js (226:36)
async DevServer.run
file:/Users/adk/Projects/myproject/nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js (606:29)
async DevServer.run
file:/Users/adk/Projects/myproject/nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js (450:20)
async DevServer.handleRequest
file:/Users/adk/Projects/myproject/nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js (321:20)
```

Next.js version: 12.1.6,
Node version: 16.15.1

File structure

```
nextjs
├── package.json
├── next.config.js
├── tsconfig.json
├── pages
│   ├── _app.tsx
│   ├── api
│   │   └── auth
│   │       ├── _middleware.ts
│   │       └── login.tsx
│   └── index.tsx
```

I'm confused as to why `NextResponse.next()` is not working for me, and would really appreciate help with implementing `next()`. Thank you.

Comment: Your code [seems to work fine here](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-yonath-e0f7ox?file=/pages/_middleware.ts) (refresh the in-browser pane then look at the terminal output).

Comment: @MarkG That's strange... The terminal output is just `error - TypeError: resolver is not a function`, nothing else. Would providing the Call Stack be helpful?

Comment: Sure, why not. Someone else out there might notice something that we haven't. Since the code works in that remote sandbox, it's probably something related to your local setup.

Comment: What happens if you remove the line `export default authMiddleware` and change the function signature to match [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#usage): `export function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent)`?

Comment: @MarkG I was exporting `login.tsx` the wrong way. It was working fine on its own but with middleware it had to be a default export declared explicitly. After that the `TypeError` was gone but I was getting an API error saying I wasn't returning a response. I moved the middleware and `login.tsx` out of both api and auth folders and it worked. I must be misunderstanding the point of the `api` folder/route. Must be more complicated than just a namespace. Thank you so much for your help, you were instrumental in figuring this out :)